# iPad3 web app splash screen not working in landscape mode

Tags: ipad, html, web-applications, splash-screen

I built a HTML5 webapp for iPad which used the splash screen for landscape and portrait mode.
I used the below link tags to get it to work.

```
<link media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}ipad/img/Default-Landscape.png" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"/>
<link media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}ipad/img/Default-Portrait.png" rel="apple-touch-startup-image"/>
```

The images work well for iPad1 and 2 however, with iPad3 the splash screen in landscape mode appears out of place, the portrait mode works okay. Do I have to use a different image for landscape mode or have to change the link tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Size for high-resolution iPad launch images (in pixels):**
1536 x 2008 (portrait)
2048 x 1496 (landscape)
Source: [apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

Add this to your media query:
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) to target the new iPad, e.g:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/ipad-landscape-retina.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
```

Comment: Thanks Amoeba! It worked like a charm. I ended up using two link tags for landscape mode to support ipad1&2 and ipad3. <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}ipad/img/Default-Landscape.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}ipad/img/retina_landscape.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />

Comment: It seems pretty lame we need to make like 30 different sizes of splash screen